GitLab Runner, how to troubleshot "Skipping Git Submodules Setup"
I have a project with submodules. I setup a pipeline to build the code but I keep getting the message: Skipping Git Submodules Setup.
I read many posts and implemented the proposed suggestions:

use relative paths on the .gitmodules
add the repo to the "Job token permissions"
setup the "GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY" and "GIT_SUBMODULE_FORCE_HTTPS" variables
call "git submodule update --init" on the script

but it still does not work.
My next step would be to enable some type of logging that could show me what is the problem and I could then try to fix it.
So my questions are:

Is there a way to get more information out of the pipeline on why GitLab is skipping the Submodules setup?
I am missing something on setup?

Thanks!!
John

Forgot to mention: I am using an on-site GitLab Server, version 15.11.00
